# Uncaught ReferenceError: cycleImages is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive defined the function cycleImages in my javascript but for some reason its undefined heres my code:

```
<script>

        (function($) {
            function cycleImages(){
                var $active = $('#cycler .active');
                var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
                $next.css('z-index',2);
                $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){
                    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
            })
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually capturing the function, you're just passing a string:

```
setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
```

So when the window tries to execute it, it's going to evaluate that string and execute the code therein.  By that time, you're outside of the scope of your enclosure and the function is indeed not defined.

You can capture a reference to the function by using the actual function instead of a string:

```
setInterval(cycleImages, 7000);
```

Comment: Thanks you're the best and sorry but cause I'm below 15 rep it looks like I cant up vote you.